# Reversing a string with C++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s="PIZZA";
    int le=s.length();
    for(int i=le-1;i=0;i--){
        cout<<s[i];
    }

}
```

What is the error here? I am not getting any output.

Answer (score 1):

You 'd mean `i >= 0` in the for loop.
Otherwise you never enter it. `i = 0` results to 0 which results to `false`.

Please do learn how to use the debugger, you will solve most of your problems with it. Unrelated: Don't use `using namespace std` globally, avoid reverse-iterating for loops.

Comment: Reverse iterating: `for (auto it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); it++) cout << *i;`

Answer (score 0):

the condition of the loop is wrong,we want loop from last index of string into first the whole range so you should use i>=0 instead of i=0

worked code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "PIZZA";
    for(int i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    cout<<str[i];
}
```

but you'd better know that with this code we only print string from end not Reverse IT !! to reverse we use this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "PIZZA";
    string rev="";
    for(int i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    rev+=str[i];
    cout<<"Reverse = "<<rev;
}
```

concat items from last of the string into new one !

Comment: Another option to reverse any container, even `std::string`, is to use [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) instead.

Answer (score -2):

You would have gotten your answer without asking us if you had turned on compiler warnings:

[Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

That would have [given you](https://godbolt.org/z/GP7qxraMG):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:9:21: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
    9 |     for(int i=le-1;i=0;i--){
      |                    ~^~
Compiler returned: 0
```

So the compiler is saying: "You are performing an assignment, then using the result as a boolean value/condition. Are you sure that's what you want to do?"

Now, other answers told you what to replace `i=0` with (it's `i>=0`, or possibly `i != -1`). But - with the warning above, I'm pretty sure you could have reached this conclusion yourself.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but what's OP going to do with this warning? If they replace `=` with `==`, it won't help much.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I didn't suggest OP replace = with ==. Let me clarify that.